# Launch webserver with no configuration file

Tags: apache, webserver, lighttpd, heredoc

I really like the concept of firing up an HTTP daemon to serve something like the current working directory in the file system without the distraction of configuring modules, directories, permissions etc. (instant gratification for programmers). My example use-cases are:

- I may be trying to prototype some RESTful web services with a new UI framework, or
- provide a tutorial for users to use some UI framework with a realistic but minimal end-to-end sample code.
- experimenting with making an SVN or Git repository available over HTTP (no lectures about security or alternative protocols please)
- making my personal files (photos, documents,...) available temporarily over HTTP while I am out of town (particularly abroad where all I would have is a plugin-less browser at an internet cafe)

Here's one I found from another thread:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Is there an equivalent, ideally, with Apache httpd? Lighttpd is a candidate too but once you create prerequisites you lose adopters of the technology you are trying to teach (or learn yourself). The best tutorials are one liners you can copy and paste to execute, then figure out how it works after seeing it in action.

I'm guessing the answer is no, not directly BUT you can use a heredoc in place of your httpd.conf file? It would be nicer if the popular binaries had direct command line arguments.

Comment: A lot of lightweight Python web servers can be used for your REST service prototype, such as bottle, flask and really any [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) compatible ones. And often these dedicated HTTP server solutions you mentioned in question are just used as proxy to expose your Python servers to public `:80` port.

Comment: Indeed, Python is the best option I've seen so far (I found bottle very convenient as in my rest sample here: https://github.com/sarnobat/angular-rest-json/blob/master/server/rest.py). Though the problem is that I would either have to ship the additional module bottle.py or ask a tutorial consumer to install it, so my search is not over yet.

Comment: I fully understand your concerns. Have you considered writing one bash file that takes care of the deployment and/or execution of the server? Or, if the tutorial actually does mention about the server implementation, a `pip install bottle` command doesn't really hurt that much :) Because to me, Apache httpd would be a prerequisite that I wouldn't install on my local environment, if I were a consumer of such a tutorial

Comment: Yes I do have a shell script: https://github.com/sarnobat/angular-rest-json/blob/master/server.sh (other ones even have xdg-open || open to launch a browser page). But once "magic" occurs in any scripts, users have to trust that it will work correctly (a trust I don't have for most shell scripts). As for Apache being preinstalled, I place Windows programmers below OS X and Ubuntu in my priorities (rightly or wrongly I'd have to investigate). The *nix environments have some form of Apache preinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

This runs lighttpd in the foreground on port 8080, serving files from `/www`.  Ctrl-C to cause lighttpd to exit:

`printf 'server.document-root="/www" \n server.port=8080' | lighttpd -D -f -`